Vlookup to return values ​according to the number of occurrences in repeated intervals
In table 1 there is a range of codes that may be repeated, but with different values ​​for each code:



Table 1





Cod.
Value


qwe
2


asd
3


zxc
8


rty
12


fgh
14


vbn
15


qwe
16


zxc
18


rty
20


qwe
23



Table 2 contains the same codes as table 1, but ordered differently:



Table 2





Cod.
Find


asd



fgh



qwe



qwe



qwe



rty



rty



vbn



zxc



zxc




I need to fetch the values ​​from table 1 into table 2, so that:

the first occurrence of a code in table 2 search for the first
occurrence of the same code in table 1;
the second occurrence of a code in table 2 search for the second
occurrence of the same code in table 1;
and so on.

I came up with the formula below, but to no avail:
=ÍNDICE($B$2:$B$10; CORRESP(1; ($A$2:$A$10=F2)*(CONT.SE($F$2:F2;F2)=CONT.SE($A$2:$A$10; F2)); 0))

Below is the simulation spreadsheet.
Test


You may try:
=map(J3:J12;lambda(Σ;chooserows(filter(B:B;A:A=Σ);countif(J3:Σ;Σ))))


